# Production never redirect to https even api is enable for https redirect

Tags: asp.net-core, hsts

I am working on asp.net core 2.1 API. The api is working as expected on all environment. recently we enable it for HSTS headers. so added below code in startup.cs -> ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddHsts(options =>
            {
                options.Preload = true;
                options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
            });
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
                options.HttpsPort = int.Parse(443);
            });
```

When I check response from postman on dev environment for http request
it give me 302 redirect status code. which is as expected

But on Production for http request, 
It gives me 404 File or directory not found.

'''''''''''''''''''''
In Configure method we have
'''''''''

```
app.UseHsts()
   .UseHttpsRedirection();
```

I am expecting that on Production also I should get 302 status code instead of 404.

Did I miss any other setting. Why postman is show 404 on production but 302 on dev envirment when code is same on both envirment

Comment: Why 302 when your code shows 301?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found "http" binding is missing on server. Adding http along with https works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ASP.NET Core has some logic to detect if you have correct HTTPS listener configured. But if you don't enable some additional configuration, like `IISIntegration`, or self HTTPS hosting, it was impossible for ASP.NET Core to know that the web server supports HTTPS.

So we read the source code of the `UseHTTPSRedirection` on GitHub and built our own middleware to redirect all traffic to HTTPS. Like this:

```cs
namespace YourApp.Middlewares
{
    public class EnforceHttpsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public EnforceHttpsMiddleware(
            RequestDelegate next,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            ILogger<EnforceHttpsMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            // Use this bool to trigger HSTS.
            var hsts = false;
            if (hsts && !context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Strict-Transport-Security"))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=15552001; includeSubDomains; preload");
            }
            else if (!context.Request.IsHttps)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Insecure HTTP request handled! Redirecting the user...");
                await HandleNonHttpsRequest(context);
            }
            else
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }

        protected virtual async Task HandleNonHttpsRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!string.Equals(context.Request.Method, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            }
            else
            {
                var optionsAccessor = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>();
                var request = context.Request;
                var host = request.Host;
                if (optionsAccessor.Value.SslPort.HasValue && optionsAccessor.Value.SslPort > 0)
                {
                    host = new HostString(host.Host, optionsAccessor.Value.SslPort.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    host = new HostString(host.Host);
                }
                var newUrl = string.Concat(
                    "https://",
                    host.ToUriComponent(),
                    request.PathBase.ToUriComponent(),
                    request.Path.ToUriComponent(),
                    request.QueryString.ToUriComponent());

                context.Response.Redirect(newUrl, permanent: true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use your middleware like this:

```cs
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseEnforceHttps(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            return app.UseMiddleware<EnforceHttpsMiddleware>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseEnforceHttps();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

Only in a production environment, this middleware will help you handle HTTP requests and redirect them to HTTPS.